# Find the smallest $n\in \mathbb N$ s.t. these fractions are irreducible

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Find the smallest $n\in \mathbb N$ such that these fractions $$\frac{19}{n+19}, \frac{20}{n+20},...,\frac{91}{n+91}$$
> are irreducible.

My attempt:

First : proving that these fractions are irreducible for some $n$ is equivalent to prove that $$\gcd(n,x)=1, \forall x\in \{a\in \mathbb N\mid 19\le a \le 91\}=A$$

**Claim 1:**

$n$ Cannot be even.

**Proof:**

Suppose that $n$ is even, then $n=2y, y\in \mathbb N$ so for even numbers in the set $A$ we have $x=2z$:
$$\frac{x}{n+x}=\frac{2z}{2y+2z} \implies \gcd(n,x)=2>1$$
**Claim 2:**
$n$ can't be equals to $x$.

**Proof:**
Suppose that $n=x$, Then: $$\frac{x}{n+x}=\frac{x}{2x}\implies \gcd(n,x)=x>1$$

So with these two restrictions, we are left with $n\in \{b\in \mathbb N \mid b\in ]0,19[ \cup ]91,\infty[ \}$

**Claim 3:**

the smallest possible value for $n$ is $n=1$

**Proof**

To prove this claim is is sufficient to prove that $n=1$ is a solution to the problem,  because there is no $n<1$ which satisfies the two restrictions.

I'm gonna prove that $\gcd(x, x+n)=\gcd(x,x+1)=1$ for all $x \in \mathbb N$:

By the way of contradictions suppose $\exists d>1$ s.t. $d\mid x,x+1$, so we have $$\cases{x\equiv 0 \pmod d\\ x+1 \equiv 0\pmod d} \implies x+1\equiv x \pmod d \iff d\mid 1$$

which means that $d=1$, but this is a contradiction.

I think that my solution is too long for a math contest problem because in math competitions you have to have a short answer to get time to do the other problems. So if there exists a short or a better solution to the problem, please post it.

Comment: You don't need Claims 1 and 2. Once you prove $n=1$ satisfies the condition, you already know it is the minimal possible.

Comment: My guess is that $n=1$ is not the desired answer (as it is too obviously a solution).  In any case, if you are practicing contest problems, you might want to try for the next largest.

Comment: Would the Corrector accept this as a full answer? @KentaS

Comment: @Yassir it is a logically correct proof, so they should accept it.

Comment: Are you sure this is a contest problem? Because, $n=1$ satisfies your fractions. Therefore, you need only putting $n=1.$ So, there is no need any mathematical proof/manipulations.

Comment: @lonestudent yeah i’m sure that this is a math contest problem.

Comment: But then I expect they want $n>1$.  As I say, taking $n=1$ is a trivial solution.

Comment: @Yassir you are probably missing something. $n=1$ holds for fractions . And there doesn't exist a positive integer such that $n<1$ . So, the proof is completed.

Comment: @lulu I think you are right.  But if there is an upper limit, of course.

Comment: @lonestudent, Oh, I figured the top term was the one with $91$.  Which would make the answer equal to the least prime $>91$, a.k.a. $n=97$.

Comment: @lulu I don't think if we suppose $n >1$ then the answer must be the least prime > 91. The answer should be the smallest $n$ such that $gcd(n,i) = 1 \quad \forall i = 20,..,91$. If after that, this $n$ is equal to the least prime > 91, then it's a coincidence.

Comment: @lulu Maybe, it would be a good idea to check fractions on a computer with a little code before doing the math. Maybe...

Comment: @lonestudent  Am I missing something?  Each integer $>1$ is divisible by some prime $p$.  If you had an example less than $97$ then it would be divisible by some prime in $\{2,\cdots, 89\}$.  It is easy to see that there is at least one $k\in \{19, \cdots, 91\}$ which is divisible by that prime, so...

Comment: @lulu Yes, with your lastest argument then $n$ must be indeed the least prime > 91.

Comment: @lulu I agree with you.

Comment: I want to mention that by $\mathbb N$ I mean the nonnegative integers, so $n=1$ is not a trivial solution @lulu

Comment: I think it is clear what $\mathbb  N$ means.  But $n=1$ is still a trivial solution.  All you need is the remark that $\gcd(k,k+1)=1$ for all natural numbers $k$, but of course $d\,|\,k$ and $d\,|\,(k+1)$ would imply that $d\,|\,1$.
=

Comment: @Yassir ....$n=1$ is a nonnegative integer, so this is trivial unfortunately, I mean you need only to check $n=1$. So it is enough for your proof....

Comment: @lulu do you think we have upper bound for maximum value of $n?$ Because, by euclidean algorithm $\gcd(a,n+a)=\gcd(n,a)$ isn't it? I checked $n=10^{17}+1$ and it works. So, I think we have no upper bounds. Did I miss something?

Comment: @lonestudent  There is no upper bound on the maximum. Any prime $>91$ works as does every product of such primes.

Comment: @lulu thanks. I mean if $\gcd(19,n)=\gcd(20,n)=\gcd(91,n)=1$, we can take $$n=19×20×91×k+1, k\in\mathbb Z^{+}$$

Comment: @lonestudent  Well, you need all the factors from $19$ to $91$, or at least the primes from $2$ to $89$.    I think it's better to use the primes because that gives you all the solutions at once.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ you have $\gcd(x,x+1)=\gcd(x,1)=1$ for all $x$, and $n=1$ is clearly minimal.

I wouldn't say this solution is too long for a math contest.